# Помогите с оператором эквивалентности

Tags: php

Помогите разобраться, ответ должен быть **15b** но браузер показывает **15**:

```
$a = 5; //тип integer
$b = "10b"; //тип string
$sum = $a + $b;
echo "Сумма двух чисел = $sum";
```

Comment: Дайте полные условия задачи. Из `5` и `"10b"` можно многими способами получить `"15b"`, но что-то мне подсказывает, большинство будут работать только с `5`и `"10b"`, а с другими данными результат будет ошибочный.

Answer (score 2):

Приведенный Вами пример иллюстрирует [автоматическое приведение типов](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.type-juggling.php) в `php`

Так как `+` является оператором сложения **чисел**, строка `"10b"` преобразовывается в число. Если использовать оператор сложения строк `.`, получится `510b`. В любом случае, ответ никак не должен быть `15b`.

**Оператор эквивалентности** `===` нужен тогда, когда нужно сравнить не только результаты выражений, но также их типы, например:

```
var_dump(10 == "10b");      // true
var_dump(10 === "10b");     // false
```

Comment: ну и чего `15b` то как из этого получить?

Comment: @teran `$sum = ($a + $b) . preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $b);` xD

Comment: @teran я нашел статью, где этот пример, и исходя из контекста статьи подумал, что вопрос не в получении `15b` https://alekseygulynin.ru/operator-ekvivalentnosti-v-php/

Comment: да, похоже на то, что автор думает, что из этого должно получиться `15b`, а не хочет получить это значение

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов на самом деле вы правы я на этом сайте нашел задание, и подумал что его надо решить. А как надо это правильно решить? Может быть я не правильно прочитал.

Comment: @EminMammadov решать там не нужно, нужно просто запустить код и проанализировать результат, что мы и сделали. `15` - это то, что должно получиться, и так получается потому, что в выражении `$a + $b` `10b` приводится просто к `10`